# Select range of non-identical date from different table

Tags: mysql, join, select

On MySQL5 with innoDB, I have sensor data in multiple tables, all with an ID and a DATETIME field, like so (two tables shown, but there are more). The IDs and DATETIMEs are not identical between tables, as each sensor uploads at a different rate.

temp_data:

```
INT      id
DATETIME ts
FLOAT    temp
FLOAT    humidity
FLOAT    lux
```

power_data:

```
INT      id
DATETIME ts
FLOAT    kW
FLOT     volts
```

My question is:
I need to pull all rows within a certain date range from BOTH table- in this case, the last 12 hours, so, the most recent N rows, but in the future, any date range in the past.  These will be sorted by the DATETIME value.

Using the (very good!) answer below, I get:

`sourceTable    id  ts Ascending        temp    humd    lux
power   19879   2015-05-16 18:13:08 0.5 121.9   NULL
temp    19880   2015-05-16 18:13:10 76  44  1099
power   19880   2015-05-16 18:13:12 0.51    122 NULL
temp    19881   2015-05-16 18:13:13 76  44  1102`

...and so on.  I need to preserve the column headers to parse this in JSON using PHP.  Is there a way to do that?  For instance, the volts/kW column headers are gone in this example.  I could write some PHP which looks for a NULL in the third position or check the sourceTable field, so I'm considering this answer correct.  However, I am interested to know if there's a way to keep the headers.

Comment: Regarding your edit, it isn't possible for SQL to have a result set where a single column has more than one identifier. You would either check the sourceTable field in your PHP and have some logic there, or run multiple queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no connection between these two tables, so a join won't really get what you need. If everything goes into a single result set, you need to UNION them together. Note that when doing a union, you get one set of columns, and you can't mix datatypes within a column (no concern here since all your data are FLOATs). Here's an example starting point:

```
SELECT
  'temp' AS sourceTable,
  id,
  ts,
  temp AS measure1,
  humidity AS measure2,
  NULL AS measure3
FROM 
  temp_data
WHERE 
  ts >= @StartDate AND
  ts <= @EndDate
UNION ALL
SELECT
  'power' AS SourceTable,
  id,
  ts,
  lux AS Measure1,
  kw AS Measure2,
  volts AS Measure3
FROM 
  power_data
WHERE
  ts >= @StartDate AND
  ts <= @EndDate
```

Comment: I was thinking the same thing as @Nicholai, but what you really need is some way of distinguishing Temp_Data from Power_Data - create an extra field on both tables - call it Rec_Type SMALLINT - 1 = Temp_Data, 2 = Power_Data.

Comment: the table name tells us what type of data it is, we don't need to create a column that is the same for every row in that table. we do that with the first field in each select.

Comment: No - when you UNION the results, you'll need to be able to tell if the record is a Temp or a Power record - that data will be lost with the UNION.

Comment: please re-read the query. it is the first field, called SourceTable.

Comment: Sorry - my apologies - I missed that part of your SQL. Elegant approach! +1.

Comment: So, I'm getting an empty set when I try this (I tried a similar union before...).  I think it's because they aren't all FLOATS like I describe in the question (in reality, I have a lot of sensors... some are INTS or DECIMAL).  Is there a solution for that?

Comment: If you're getting an empty set (as opposed to an error), then your WHERE clause is excluding all records (or your tables themselves have 0 rows).

Comment: Okay, this works almost 100%.  Here is my output using this query:

This works well, with the source table identifying which results came from which table.  
My quesiton is: this need to be parsed into JSON with PHP so I need to preserve the column titles.  Is there any way to do that (or a clever PHP way not involving column titles?)